# Python replacing letters with radom from a list result is not what i expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a code generator and in a loop if it finds a letter it should replace it with a letter from a randomized list. When running the code to replace itself so like a with a, b with b
it works. But when I'm trying the same thing with the randomized list it starts messing up such as replacing it with the wrong letters. Here's an example of my code:

```
text = input("Input text: ")
textsplit = [char for char in text]
result = text
push = -1
listpush = -1
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
codelist = letters
random.shuffle(codelist)
for i in textsplit:
    push = push + 1
    if i == "a":
        listpush = 0
        result = result.replace(result[push], codelist[listpush])
    elif i == "b":
        listpush = 1
        result = result.replace(result[push], codelist[listpush])
    elif i == "c":
        listpush = 2
        result = result.replace(result[push], codelist[listpush])
    elif i == "d":
        listpush = 3
        result = result.replace(result[push], codelist[listpush])
    elif i == "e":
        listpush = 4
        result = result.replace(result[push], codelist[listpush])
    elif i == "f":
        listpush = 5
        result = result.replace(result[push], codelist[listpush])
    elif i == "g":
        listpush = 6
        result = result.replace(result[push], codelist[listpush])
print(result)
print(*codelist, sep="|")
```

here's an example of the result of running the code:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wxsm.png)

The first two letters are fine but the third should have been replaced with g and there shouldn't be two "e". I'm new to python i probably made a small mistake but i cant find it.
Could anyone help in what I did  wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to note that if you want to change letter for letter python has built-in device for it - `.translate` method of `str` and `.maketrans` for building table of changes, consider following example

```
src = "abcdefg"
dst = "abgdfec"
t = str.maketrans(src, dst)
intext = "abcdefg"
outtext = intext.translate(t)
print(outtext)
```

Output:

```
abgdfec
```

Explanation: `maketrans` when given two `str`s of equal length will create `dict` to be used in `.translate` which will cause changing characters present in first argument to corresponding characters from second argument. `maketrans` also accept optional third argument - characters to remove.

If you want to know more about `maketrans` or `translate` read [this medium.com article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/when-and-where-to-use-maketrans-and-translate-in-python-764670ff91fe)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `result[push]` and replace it with just `result` and do the same with `codelist[listpush]`, see if this works

Comment: It doesn't work. If i change it to those they are not strings but lists so replace just doesn't work and puts out an error message.

Comment: maybe try keeping push as 0

Comment: because what your doing is, ``replace`` works with two arguments you would do ``replace(#what you want to replace, #what you want to replace it with)``

Answer (score 0):

when you call `replace` method of the string you replace *all* occurences of match text in it with replacement text. Try replacing them one by one, like this

```
text = input("Input text: ")
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
codelist = letters.copy()
random.shuffle(codelist)
print(codelist)

code = {letter:codepoint for letter,codepoint in zip(letters, codelist)}
result = [code[letter] for letter in text]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the replace function it will replace all occurrences of that character in the string, what happened for you is that the c was replaced by g and later on that g was replaced again by a c.

What you can do is create a predefined dictionary where the keys and values are equal and shuffle it like so.

```
text = input("Input text: ")
# prepare a dict where each key is a supported letter in you dbc and each value is a valid replacement
letters = {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "b",
    "d": "d",
    "e": "e",
    "f": "f",
    "g": "g"
}
keys = list(letters.keys())
values = list(letters.values())
# shuffle the values
random.shuffle(values)
letters_shuffled = dict(zip(keys, values))

# create a new string replacing all characters, if a character is not defined, it will remain the same
shuffled_text = ''.join([letters_shuffled.get(char, char) for char in text])

print(shuffled_text)
```